# Rails 4 form bootstrap fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am using https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms gem. I am getting double labels in my html output and input fields are stretching 100% width. How do I fix it? 
This is my devise new.html.erb:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This is my html output:

```
  <div><label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_email">Email</label><input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="" /></div></div>

  <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_password">Password</label><input class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" /></div></div>

  <div><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />
  <div class="form-group"><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><input class="form-control" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" type="password" /></div></div>

  <div><input class="btn btn-default" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign up" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting duplicate fields because the `email_field`, `password_field`, etc. helpers already put labels in there for you. So you really just need this:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
<%= f.password_field :password %> 
etc...
```

Your fields are 100% width because that is what Bootstrap 3 defaults to. Specifically, see the [Bootstrap Documentation for Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), which says:

```
All textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select> elements with
.form-control are set to width: 100%; by default.
```